# Trigger redirect on option selected

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following `select` tag with options populated from a Mongo database, and would like to have the latest `option` tag to redirect me to my template to create new options.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="perfume_type" name="perfume_type">
    <option disabled selected>Choose type</option>
    {% for type in types %}
        <option value="{{ type.type_name }}">{{ type.type_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option value="{{ url_for('new_type') }}">Create new type...</option>
</select>
```

What would be the best approach to trigger automatically that redirect when the last option (outside the loop) is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with simple Javascript and HTML. You need to do the following changes:

1. Add an `onchange` even on the `select` tag.

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="perfume_type" name="perfume_type" onchange="checkSelected()">
```

2. Add the JavaScript method, which will check whether it's the last selected option or not. If it's the last selected option, then redirect.

```html
<script>
    function checkSelected() {
        var selected = document.getElementById('perfume_type');
        var option = selected.options[selected.options.length-1];
        if (option.selected == true) {
            window.location = option.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope the above works.

Comment: Oh this works perfect!! Thank you so much!
It would be amazing if that same behaviour could also happen when I select one of the perfume types, so then it redirects to the route without me having to click on "Submit". 
Would you like me to make a new question about that?

Comment: Perhaps a new question would be better, as the form changed a bit since this was posted!

Comment: Great! Here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61974793/automatically-redirect-on-option-selected