# Automatically redirect on option selected

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have the following select with a submit button.
I would really like for the option selected to redirect to my route without me needing to press a submit button, so I could get rid of it.

```
<form action="{{ url_for("perfumes.filters") }}" class="search-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Filter by Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="filter_query" name="filter_query" onchange="checkSelected()">
            <option selected='true' name="" value="" id="">Please select a type</option>
            {% for type in types %}
            <option value="{{type['type_name']}}" id="{{type['type_name']}}" name="{{type['type_name']}}">{{type['type_name']}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            <option value="{{ url_for('types.new_type') }}">Create new type...</option>
        </select><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The last option (Create New Type) is already redirecting to its corresponding route with this function.

```
function checkSelected() {
    const selected = document.getElementById("filter_query");
    const option = selected.options[selected.options.length - 1];
    if (option.selected == true) {
        window.location = option.value;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to adapt that function so I can suppress the "Submit" button and have the redirect automatically triggered on selection?

UPDATE:

This is all now working well, but I get a console error when the option outside the loop gets selected

```
<form  id="form" action="{{ url_for("perfumes.filters") }}" class="search-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Filter by Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="filter_query" name="filter_query">
            <option selected='true' name="" value="" id="">Please select a type</option>
            {% for type in types %}
            <option value="{{ url_for('perfumes.filters', filter_query=type['type_name']) }}">{{type['type_name']}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            <option value="{{ url_for('types.new_type') }}">Create new type...</option>
        </select><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the script:

```
function checkSelected() {
    if (this.value) window.location = this.value;
}
const EL_select = document.querySelector("#filter_query");
EL_select.addEventListener("change", checkSelected);
```

Comment: are you looking for `$router.push`? You could put that into `checkSelected`

Comment: To which URL you want it to get redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to:

- Last option (having a value of i.e: `"some/route"`) should navigate to that route
- All other options (which value is not empty) should submit the form immediately

If so than this might help:

```js
function checkSelected() {
  if (this.value === "some/route") return (window.location = this.value);
  if (this.value) this.form.submit();
}

const EL_select = document.querySelector("#filter_query");
if (EL_select) EL_select.addEventListener("change", checkSelected);
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="filter_query" name="filter_query">
    <option selected value="">Please select a type</option>
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="etc">etc</option>
    <option value="xxx">Create new type...</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

PS:

- Stop using inline JS (`onchange="checkSelected()"`)
- SELECT should have the name attribute, not OPTION elements

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I'm using the second, commented line as I need the options in the loop to go to my 'perfumes.filters' route (and that is happening now!).
But the last option, outside the loop, should take me to `types.new_type` instead of the same route as the others. I hope I make sense?

Comment: So this should be the one for the items in the loop:

`if (this.value) this.closest('form').submit();`

And this one for the last option, outside the loop:

`if (this.value) window.location = this.value;`

:)

Comment: Mmmm it is working, but maybe not clean: I have a console error when the option outside the loop is selected: 

El_select is null.

I'll update the question with my current code! :D

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta do you know by memory (is it a fixed value?)? What should be the value of the last option? If so, than the first line of the function should be something like `if (this.value === "blah") return location = this.value;`

Comment: This works perfectly Roko, I really appreciate this! It deals with both the values in the options in the loop and the one outside the loop. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `submit()` method programmatically when option change.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const select = document.querySelector("select");

select.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  console.log(value);
  form.submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="form" action="{{ url_for("perfumes.filters") }}" class="search-form">
    <select name="filter_query" id="select">
      <option>Select Option</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    <select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to redirected to some `/filte_selected/<id>` type of URL, on selecting an option.

You can do the following change for `option` tag:

```html
<option value="{{ url_for('filter_selected', id=type['type_name']) }}" id="{{type['type_name']}}" name="{{type['type_name']}}">{{type['type_name']}}</option>
```

You can change your scrip to:

```html
<script>
    function checkSelected() {
        var selectedValue = document.querySelector('#options').value
        if (selectedValue) {
            window.location = selectedValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it made me realise how to add the right values to my options and make the chosen answer work properly!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pull the selected value directly off of the `select` element. Then, simply redirect users to that value.

```js
function checkSelected() {
  const value = document.querySelector("#select-id").value;
  console.log(value);
  // window.location = value;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-id" onchange="checkSelected()">
  <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
</select>
```